# State of SocketJsClient not updating

Tags: reactjs, websocket, stomp

I'm trying to set a state having the value of SocketJsClient's ref from 'react-stomp' library

[This useEffect never gets called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBKdA.png)

I don't know what to try other than what it's seen. The use effect should be called after the state updates but it just doesn't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `useState` to handle refs. You should initialize your client with `const stompClientRef = useRef()` and then within your SockJsClient declare the ref attribute with

```
ref={stompClientRef}
```